# R Regression Loop Variable Name

Tags: r

I am running a regression in a loop of the following form:

`regression[[i]] <- glm(as.formula(paste(depvars[i],"~",indepvars[j],"+ var1 + var2 + var3 + factor(city) + factor(year)"))`

Where "depvars" and "indepvars" are two vectors with outcome and treatment variables. Further, I have a variable "var4" specific for each [i] which is called "var4[i]" (e.g. for i=name, the variable is called "var4name"). I want to add this variable in the regression but only for the corresponding [i]. In Stata I know I could just add in the regression "+ var4[i]" and it would work but everything I have tried in R does not seem to work. I was wondering if it is possible to do this in R?

Thank you very much,

Max

Comment: In the loop above, it looks like you're looping over two indices - `i` and `j`, but your output list is only over the `i`.  Did you mean to do `depvars[i]` and `indepvars[i]`?  For the `var4` piece, do you have a vector of names to attach to `var4` - for example, if `depvars[1]="y"` and `indepvars[1]="x"` and `"name"` is the value you want to attach to `var4`, you would have `y ~ x + var2 + var3 + var4name + factor(city) + factor(year)` as you formula for your first loop over `i`?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick reply. Sorry if my question was confusing. Basically my y variables in vector depvars[i] are the vote for a specific party (republicans, democrats) and the var4 I want to add is whether the person voted for that party in the previous election, so "voterepublicans" for republicans and "votedemocrats" for democrats, but I do not want to add both variables in both regressions. So when depvar=republicans, var4=voterepublicans and when depvar=democrats, var4=votedemocrats. I have both variables created byt not in a vector. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
depvars <- c("republicans", "democrats")
indepvars <- c("x")
library(glue)
i <- 1
j <- 1
form <- glue("{depvars[i]} ~ {indepvars[j]} + var1 + var2 + var3 + {ifelse(depvars[i] == 'republicans', 'voterep', 'votedem')} + factor(city) + factor(year)")
form
# republicans ~ x + var1 + var2 + var3 + voterep + factor(city) + factor(year)
i <- 2
form <- glue("{depvars[i]} ~ {indepvars[j]} + var1 + var2 + var3 + {ifelse(depvars[i] == 'republicans', 'voterep', 'votedem')} + factor(city) + factor(year)")
form
# democrats ~ x + var1 + var2 + var3 + votedem + factor(city) + factor(year)
```

Comment: Thank you again! Yes this would work but would it be possible to only have one regression line? Something that gives the two results you show but using only one regression that includes the iteration. So if depvar[i]=republicans, var4=voterepublicans, and since the name of depvar[i] is also included in var4, I was thinking of having "vote[i]" in the regression so that when [i]=republicans it becomes "voterepublicans" and when [i]=democrats, it becomes "votedemocrats". Thank you again for all the helpful advice!

Comment: @maxjohnson I don't see the example in your comment

Comment: Sorry I meant something along the lines of: "{depvars[i]} ~ {indepvars[j]} + var1 + var2 + var3 + vote[i] + factor(city) + factor(year)

Comment: @maxjohnson sure you would probably need `{vote[i]}` and `vote` would have to be a vector of `voterep` and `votedem` that matched up with the dependent variable.

Comment: thanks a lot but I am not sure I follow, how do I match it up with the dependent variable?